# Comparison results of regression analysis of two data

Tags: regression

I'm investigation the relationship between two variables (x and y) in a number of different datasets, and I'm looking for a suitable method to compare regression parameters when the model uses restricted cubic splines (as the relationship is not linear). The sample data is based on R's `iris` dataset:

```
library(rms)
ir.1 <- iris[,c(1,2)]; names(ir.1) <- c("x", "y")
ir.2 <- iris[,c(3,4)]; names(ir.2) <- c("x", "y")

m.1 <- ols(y ~ rcs(x,3), data=ir.1)
m.2 <- ols(y ~ rcs(x,3), data=ir.2)
```

I would like to compare `m.1` and `m.2` and see whether the models are similar or not.

Comment: At first, try to fit a single model to include two regression lines.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand; I can combine all data in the same data frame and indicate where they're from with a factor - but how would this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with R, but I know how to do it.

At first, I think rcs generates another variable based on $X$, call it $Z$.

The combined dataset for regression should be like this:

```
             group  y       x      z
               0    3.25    1.9    2.4
               0    3.26    8.5    2.7 
              ...   ...     ...    ...
               1     4.78   2.6     6.5
              ...    ...    ...    ...
```

where group = 0 means data come from iris[,c(1,2)], = 1 from iris[,c(3,4)]. Suppose you can do it.

Fit a model 
$$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2Z + \alpha_0 G + \alpha_1 GX + \alpha_2 G Z +\epsilon$$
where $G$ = group.

Then checking the significance of $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2$. If $\alpha_0$ is significant, it means two groups have different intercept,...

You also can test any linear combination of $\alpha$s and $\beta$s, and group of them together. For example, you can test the null hypotheses $\alpha_0 = 0, \alpha_1 = 0, \alpha_2=0$ simultaneously, and if cannot reject this null hypothesis, maybe you can say two regression lines are no difference.

Comment: Thank you - this answers my question perfectly!